# How can I redirect a URL which contains query param to an external URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have this unknown URL which was accidentally leaked on an email to customers and I am trying to find a way to redirect it to the intended URL.

I am trying to redirect the following link:

`https://domain-name.co.uk/?utm_campaign=Christmas%20Delivery%20Dates%202022&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-8fHwrp13cEty26peEmPGQQhC8R4zof7Wtn8wJZt1qvEuVdYEewvACSs9f6NsD7r6hUpdFs`

To this PDF URL:

`https://domain-name.azureedge.net/path-to-file.pdf`

Server config:

- Apache version - 2.4.54
- cPannel version - 106.0 (build 10)

Anyone got any ideas?

I have tried the following below. However, it doesn't seem to do anything. I believe it's because my URL is a query string.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^https://domain-name.co.uk/?utm_campaign=Christmas%20Delivery%20Dates%202022&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-8fHwrp13cEty26peEmPGQQhC8R4zof7Wtn8wJZt1qvEuVdYEewvACSs9f6NsD7r6hUpdFs https://domain-name.azureedge.net/path-to-file.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after nearly pulling my hair out, I finally solved the problem with help from the Apache [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html). Here is my solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Christmas%20Delivery%20Dates%202022
RewriteCond ?#%{QUERY_STRING} ([^#]+)#([^#]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://domain-name.azureedge.net/path-to-file.pdf [L,B,NE]
</IfModule>
```

- I am first checking if the query string `Christmas%20Delivery%20Dates%202022` is in the URL.
- I then create a backreference match for the question mark, URI and the query string.
- Then redirect to the intended URL.